# What is the compiler directive to generate a detailed map file

Tags: delphi, debugging

I wish to know is there a compiler directive which I can use in my code (not from the UI) to set that the compiler/linker should generate a detailed map file.

Is there something like:

`{$MAPFILE DETAILED}`?

I am using Delphi 2009.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are 2 ways to generate a detailed .map file.

1) you must ensure the [{D+} compiler](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsdebuginformation_xml.html) directive is set, and the "Detailed Map File" option selected in the Project >Options>Linker page of the IDE.

2) Another option is using -GD From [Delphi command-line compiler](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/1565926595/appa-1-fm2xml)

```
dcc32.exe -B -DDEBUG -GD yourprojectname.dpr
```

[Delphi Compiler Directives (Embarcadero List)](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/delphicompdirectivespart_xml.html)

[Delphi Compiler Directives](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/ByType.asp?Type=Compiler%20Directive)

```
    $D      Determines whether application debug information is built
    $DebugInfo  Determines whether application debug information is built
```

Bye.

Comment: Although a list of compiler directives is nice to have, it's not useful for *this* question since there is *no* compiler directive for instructing the compiler to generate a detailed map file. Please consider making your answer more concise by removing that extraneous list.